# Add new related model to existing model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two models with a one to many relationship

```
public class Team
{
    public int TeamID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public int PlayerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to change the Team's details view to enable adding a new Player to the team

```
// GET: /Team/Details/5
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Player player = db.Players.Find(id);
    if (player == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(player);
}
```

It has been a little hard to find any info on this but from what I can gather the best way to go about this would be to add a viewmodel

```
public class TeamViewModel
{
    public Team team { get; set; }
    public Player player { get; set; }
}
```

and send that to my details view, I have not had much success with this and am not too sure if this is even the right approach.

Any links or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

***Update***

I have managed to get the details view working but now need to sort out the post method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Details(TeamViewModel tvm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        tvm.player.team = tvm.team;
        db.Players.Add(tvm.player);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(tvm);
}
```

This will create the new player but will not store the relationship so the column TeamID in the player table is empty.

***Update 2***

I have done some debugging and it seems that my teamViewModel is not storing the team data during the post.

```
// GET: /Team/Details/5
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Team team = db.Teams.Find(id);
    if (team == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    var teamViewModel = new TeamViewModel()
    {
        team = team,
        player = new Player() { Team = db.Team.Find(id) }
    };
    return View(teamViewModel);
}

// POST: /Team/Details/5
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Details(TeamViewModel teamViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Players.Add(teamViewModel.player);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(teamViewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you want to do is the following:

- Display a view with the Team's data.
- On the same view have the possibility to add a new Player.

Your view model:

```
public class TeamViewModel
{
    public Team team { get; set; }
    public Player player { get; set; }
}
```

Can handle this job. 
Team data should be fetched before generating the view. 
Player can be empty - it will just be used for the input fields generation purposes of your view.

You should change your action more less like this:

```
// GET: /Team/Details/5
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Team team= db.Team.Find(id); //assuming that this is the id of the team
    if (team== null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    var teamViewModel = new TeamViewModel() { Team = team, Player = new Player() }; 
    return View(teamViewModel);
}
```

It is a common practice to use ViewModels. Thanks to this you separate your business models from the models that are used when presenting the data to a user. What is more you can then aggregate all the data you need and you are not limited to passing just one object to the view.

Comment: Ok so I have got the view working now I just need to figure out the post method, I will update my question.